Adaptive Runge Kutta for gradient descent optimization
A version of this question was asked a couple of years ago here, but I am still not clear on why this is not used more widely (or seemingly at all).
Problem statement: Suppose you have some differentiable function $F(\vec{x})$ that you would like to minimize (or maximize).  Given some initial guess $\vec{x}_0$, please find a nearby minimum (or maximum) $\vec{x}_m = \vec{x}_0 + \sum_{i=1}^N{d\vec{x}_i}$ in as few steps $N$ as possible.
The most obvious way to approach this would be to follow the gradient of $F$ down (or up) hill, but old-fashioned steepest descent with a line search is a famously inefficient way to do this.  However, if we formulate this problem as an ODE:
$\frac{dx_i}{dt}=-\partial_iF(\vec{x}(t))$
We should be able to use some kind of numerical integration scheme to arrive at the result.  And if the problem had (possibly nonlinear) constraints you could imagine breaking up the ODE into a piece-wise continuous trajectory that projected $-\partial_iF(\vec{x}(t))$ onto the tangent space of these constraints.
In particular, if you look at the acceleration of $\vec{x}(t)$ you find:
$\frac{d^2x_i(t)}{dt^2}=-\partial_i\partial_jF(\vec{x}(t))\cdot\frac{dx_j(t)}{dt}$
So if $\vec{x}(t)$ is close to an optimum and the Hessian of $F$ around $\vec{x}(t)$ (which we need never actually compute) is positive definite, then $|\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}|$ should decay like a sum of exponentials with time constants equal to the eigenvalues of this second derivative tensor: unlike the usual ping-ponging that happens with naive line-search steepest descent methods.  Exponential growth of steps along eigenvectors with negative eigenvalues also makes it virtually impossible for this method to be absorbed into a saddle point, since the space of starting points that are transported there would be of measure zero.
Of course actually implementing this integration numerically is not trivial.  For starters, there is no obvious choice for the size $\Delta t$ of the integration step.  However, a good adaptive step Runge-Kutta method (like Tsit5 perhaps?) should be able to get there quickly.  Presumably you would want the adaptive integrator to automatically adjust the first few steps lengths to be inversely proportional to the largest eigenvalue of the Hessian, and that of the last few steps to be inversely proportional to the smallest eigenvalue.  But close to the end, where the problem is effectively one dimensional, one could maybe try to be clever and use information about prior steps (e.g. is the direction of this step the same as that of the previous step? or maybe use forward AD to compute $\partial_i\partial_jF(\vec{x}(t))\cdot\partial_jF(\vec{x}(t)$ the directional derivative of the gradient along the gradient direction) to integrate that last exponential decay exactly.
This of course fails if we had to use implicit methods, but I struggle to see a case where an adaptive step size is not good enough.  So why isn't this used in practice?

These two tasks have different objectives, as already mentioned in the last question. With gradient descent you want to go as low as possible in the current direction, or even a little bit farther. That is why usually line-search is employed. The gradient direction changes with a great angle from one step to the next. The step sizes will not be much correlated. // When you apply RK the aim is to follow as close as possible or desired the gradient flow. The gradient vectors from one step to the next change smoothly. The step size will also be smooth almost everywhere.

That much is clear.  Line searches are relatively cheap because they involve function calls without gradients.  But doing line searches exclusively along gradient directions is bad because consecutive descent directions are orthogonal to each other.  So I suppose the real question is, would this kind of RK-assisted flow downhill (which is expensive because of the many gradient evaluations) be better or worse than conjugate gradient or your favorite version of L-BFGS with a good line search algorithm?

If you start in a region that is approximately convex, then the descent methods will converge quickly. Perhaps not pure gradient descent, see the examples with a narrow zigzag path with many steps. For global search all methods will be somewhat random, each method differently from each other. I believe that with a high likelyhood the descent methods will find a region around a local minimum faster than the RK method can move away from the initial point. But due to the randomness involved this will be hard to quantify in a general fashion.

Well, the problem with things like (L-)BFGS is that they don't really handle saddle points well, and the assumption that you will randomly start close to a convex region is not very good in a high dimensional space.  I suppose that if you had access to $\partial_i\partial_jF\cdot\partial_jF$ (e.g. via forward AD of the gradient along itself) you could use $\sqrt{\frac{|\partial_jF|^2}{|\partial_i\partial_jF\cdot\partial_jF|^2}}$ as the initial step size guess for either RK or other method.  This RMS average of the eigenvalues of the Hessian should always point in the right direction.

Come to think about it, most very big problems I can think of will not have globally differentiable cost functions.  So a higher order solver would not be universally desirable.  For piecewise differentiable functions you might want to fall back on a low order method (say Heun/Ralston 2(1) or Bogacki-Shampine 3(2)) to recycle at least one of the gradients computed in a step where a discontinuity is detected
